# WebException When calling dll

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having an issue in someone else's code.  I have code in one project that calls a dll that contains the code in question.

The code I'm calling is below:

```
public void SaveCustomTemplate(string templateName, string templateValue)
        {
            var action = "SaveCustom";
            var webCient = new WebClient();
            var address = String.Format(urlFormat, rootUrl, action);
            var queryString = new NameValueCollection();
            queryString.Add("id",templateName);
            queryString.Add("key",apiKey);
            queryString.Add("html",templateValue);
            webCient.QueryString = queryString;

            try
            {
                webCient.UploadString(address,templateValue);
                templatesCache[templateName] = templateValue;
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                var msg = String.Format("Cannot save the template '{0}'. Message:{1}.  InMessage:{2}.  Response:{3}.  Source:{4}.  Stack:{5}.  Status:{6}.  TargetSite:{7}", address, e.Message, e.InnerException.Message, e.Response, e.Source, e.StackTrace, e.Status, e.TargetSite);
                throw new WebException(msg);
            }
        }
```

As youc an see I have put in a lot of error handling in their code to get to the source of the error.  From this I get this output:

```
<div class="alert success" id="SuccessMessages">Cannot save the template 'http://localhost:30001/Templates/SaveCustom'. Message:The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive..  InMessage:Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..  Response:.  Source:System.  Stack:   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String data)
   at EmailServices.TemplateLoaders.HttpTemplateLoader.SaveCustomTemplate(String templateName, String templateValue) in C:\Projects\Red2Framework\Red2Framework\EmailServices\TemplateLoaders\HttpTemplateLoader.cs:line 94.  Status:ReceiveFailure.  TargetSite:Byte[] UploadDataInternal(System.Uri, System.String, Byte[], System.Net.WebRequest ByRef)</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Sachin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UploadString as

```
reply = webCient.UploadString(address, templateValue);
```

and track the exception as it is returned by the server. Also you have to ensure that the server is not waiting for a post. If yes then use

```
reply = webCient.UploadString(address, "POST", templateValue);
```

Comment: I put the "post" action into the uploadstring method call and printed ou the reply and the result is that there is no difference and the reply is empty.

Comment: Then the possible cases if there is no bug in the server script, are that the server expects data and not string or the string contains non ascii characters and since the webclient.encoding is undefined it does not work properly.

Comment: I tried using the asynchronous version of the UploadString method and so far it seems to work.

Comment: the thing is that it (the old, non-asynch version) works sometimes and doesnt work at other times so I don't think it would be that the server expects data and not a string.

Comment: Excellent. You solved it, but now you have to find the why (optionally)

Comment: Yeah, that is always the hard bit.

Comment: Actually it isn't really solved.  The issue now is that although I don't get the errors anymore what does happen is that I get incomplete strings back from the call.

Comment: The code above pretty much is the server side code.  Is there anything else you might need?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5777/discussion-between-sachin-and-drdigit)